# How to force sympy to extract specific subexpressions?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sympy result that winds up like this:

```
from sympy import *
Vin,Vc,C1,Cs,R1,Rs,t=symbols(r'V_{in},V_{C},C_1,C_S,R_1,R_S,t')
k1=Symbol('k_1')
eqVc=Eq(Vc(t),(Rs*(exp(t*(R1+Rs)/(R1*Rs*(C1+Cs))) - 1)*Heaviside(t) + 
                     k1*(R1+Rs))*exp(-t*(R1+Rs)/(R1*Rs*(C1+Cs)))/(R1+Rs))
```

The expression `eqVc` comes out like this:

[image]

I know this function to be of the form:

[image]

My goal is to get the values of Vcinit, Vcfinal, and tau, but particularly tau.

Is there a way to get Sympy to extract these values?  cse() doesn't quite do what I want-- I can get it to replace C1+Cs, for example by using cse([C1+Cs,eqVc]), and it does recognize that the exponent to e is a common subexpression, but it tends to include the t in the subexpression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to solve for parameters which will cause the expressions to be equal at a number of points in time. Given that the forms are in fact the same, this will work fine:

```
V_Ci, tau, V_Cf = symbols('V_Ci, tau, V_Cf')

target = V_Ci*exp(-t/tau) + Heaviside(t)*V_Cf*(1 - exp(-t/tau))

solve([(eqVc.rhs - target).subs(t, ti) for ti in [0, 1, 2]],
      [V_Ci, tau, V_Cf], dict=True)
```

The answer I get is

```
[{V_Cf: R_S/(R_1 + R_S),
  tau: 1/log(exp((1/R_S + 1/R_1)/(C_1 + C_S))),
  V_Ci: k_1}]
```

That `log(exp())` is not simplified away because of the way the variables are defined. Defining everything as real (`V_Ci, tau, V_Cf = symbols('V_Ci, tau, V_Cf', real=True)` and similar modification in your code) simplifies the soluion to

```
[{V_Ci: k_1, 
  V_Cf: R_S/(R_1 + R_S), 
   tau: R_1*R_S*(C_1 + C_S)/(R_1 + R_S)}]
```

Comment: Different route than I was expecting, but it gets the job done!  It's worth pointing out that the times we're setting equality at are relatively arbitrary except there need to be at least 3 of them (to solve for the 3 unknowns) and, for some reason, t=0 needs to be included.  For some reason, solving at [1,2,3] doesn't work (or at least takes longer than I'm willing to wait).

Comment: I think at least one time needs to be on the zero side of the heaviside for the initial voltage to be calculated.